Filter by date + date range selector Looker / Google Data Studio
I have data in a Google Sheet organised like this :
enter image description here
I'd like to calculate and display in my Looker report the number of started tasks (but not necessarily ended) on a precise range of dates selected with a date range selector.
How would you do this ?
What I expect :
For instance, based on my data example, if I choose the range with my selector 1st january 2022 => 31st december 2023, it should display "2" (Task 1 and Task 2 have started on this range,Task 3 has started before the range and is out of calculation).
If I choose the range 1st january 2019 => 31st december 2019, it should display "1" (Task 3 is started on this range, Task 1 and 2 are not started yet).
